# Importing data from Adwords API to Excel

Tags: excel, api

I'd like to find a way to import keyword search volume into Excel.

Currently, I'm using Grepwords API with this Excel function:

=WEBSERVICE(http://api.grepwords.com/lookup?&FAKE-API-KEY&q=taco%20bell)

In the example above, it pulls all of Grepwords data for the keyword "taco bell" into a single cell in Excel.

Is there a way to perform the same task--albeit using the Adwords API instead of Grepwords?

If so, can someone provide an example of what that URL would look like?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the [adwords support page](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/adwords-api)?

Comment: I've shared it there--per your suggestion. But, I've had better luck here. So, if anyone has any suggestions, I'm interested.